# Conditional Formatting formula for each individual row?

Tags: formatting, openoffice-calc

I'm trying to change the background color of all cells containing "@". I've finally found a formula that works:

```
COUNTIF(A3;".@.")>0
```

Now I can't seem to figure out how to change this formula to affect each individual cell based on it's own value. For example, I want the formula to work in such a way that:

- Cell A3 is formatted if Cell A3 contains "@"
- Cell A4 is formatted if Cell A4 contains "@"
- Cell A5 is formatted if Cell A5 contains "@"
- etc.

I know I've done this before in Excel, so I'm sure there's a way to do it.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/630271/84724) solve your issue? Just select all cells that should be affected by the conditional formatting, and enter the formula so it works for the first (upmost) cell. LO / OOo will adapt the formula for the other rows automatically.

Comment: Yep, that's it... Could've sworn I'd tried that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Select ColumnA, Format > Conditional Formatting..., choose *Formula is* and enter

```
FIND("@";A1)
```

then a style of your choice and <kbd>OK</kbd>.